# Android set FrameLayout as background

Tags: android, image, android-framelayout

I have two images, and I need to put them one on another, that can be made using `FrameLayout`, as I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493855/android-how-to-put-an-image-over-another-image). However, I need to set that layout as background to one of my tabTitle, how it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that programmatically,

```
myFrameLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
myFrameLayout.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = myFrameLayout.getDrawingCache();

myAnotherLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap)));
```

Comment: can't figure out how to get this Framelayout from resources

Comment: What do you mean by "from resources"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221967/android-get-reference-to-layout-in-code

Comment: @Niko I tried this got but bitmap size is as my Screen size , and framelayout height width are grater then screen

Comment: @pcpriyanka Thats is tricky case because platform draws only to visible rect. Also consuming such a large bitmap using this method may easily cause OOM.

Comment: @Niko what can I do for that?  any idea ?

Comment: @Niko I am creating one app which include draw crop rotation and etc what I want to do is image edit and save as the original size and quality

Comment: @pcpriyanka you could dig into this library for some help: https://arthurhub.github.io/Android-Image-Cropper/

Comment: @Niko just want to create bitmap of larger framelayout but it returing width  of bitmap as screen size