# How to get a reference to an XML file from FrameLayout

Tags: android

I need to get reference to separate XML file which is FrameLayout but I can't figure out how to do it, this code doesn't work:

```
FrameLayout desktopFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.desktopsFramelayout);
desktopFrameLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
desktopFrameLayout.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = desktopFrameLayout.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Use should have to used LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For that you have to use inflate view.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);

FrameLayout item = (FrameLayout ) view.findViewById(R.id.desktopsFramelayout);
```

Comment: Just for the record you can only get system service in or after Activity's `onCreate()` is called.